# SSIS - SharePoint - Network Path Not Found

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm using SSIS to upload a PDF from SSRS into a SharePoint 2010 library. When I run the package in SSDT, it uploads as intended. However, when I deploy to the SSIS Catalog and run the package using a proxy account under SQL Server Agent, I receive the following error:

> Network path was not found

I have verified my proxy account can post to the SharePoint site as the permissions are set up correctly. My belief is SSIS is not even trying to authenticate with the SharePoint site (maybe trying to connect anonymously?).

The code that uploads the PDF is located below. It authenticates the user to SSRS successfully, but not to SharePoint. The path that it uploads to is a UNC path. How do I get it to authenticate to a UNC path? A thought was to map a drive but that seems like a hack and may not be as reliable.

```
Dim httpCon As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("DDM Report Server")
Dim clientConn As HttpClientConnection = New HttpClientConnection(httpCon.AcquireConnection(Nothing))
clientConn.ServerURL = Dts.Variables("$Package::DDM_ReportServer").Value.ToString() & Dts.Variables("Report_Filename").Value.ToString()
clientConn.DownloadFile(Dts.Variables("$Package::SharePoint_Delivery_Location").Value.ToString() & Dts.Variables("PDF_Name").Value.ToString(), True)
```

Comment: Can you login locally to the SSIS server and see if the UNC path is accessible from it?   Or get someone else at your company to do it?

Comment: Yes that works, and the SSIS package will run. But that only works for that session. When server is rebooted, it fails. I need to mimic the same functionality in code or with a connection manager.

Comment: If the authenticated user isn't the root issue, my next guess will be there is some IE driver extension issue that is not installed on the server. There's *something* that allows you to map drives to sharepoint (or treat SP as UNC paths) that I have not gotten to work on servers despite being valid on desktops.

Comment: @Todd Maybe the Service Account which using by SQL Server Agent may not have the Access to SharePoint.

Comment: FWIW - I export an Excel file from a template into a SharePoint DOCUMENTS folder using the HTTP address (`http://sharepointreports/sites/.../Documents/`) using `Workbook.SaveAs(ReportName)`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out yesterday. Hannover First, you were onto something. In SSIS, you use WebClient within a script task to authenticate to the SharePoint site using the URL instead of the UNC Path. WebClient has everything you need to authenticate.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the updated code works for you? I've tried that route but i seem to be missing something.